# How do I use the src attribute to link HTML code?

Tags: html, web

So I know in HTML you can do

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

But is it possible to somehow link a html page? For example:

```
<html src="testing.html"></html>
```

Comment: if you're using php file you can use include, but if you are not so you can go with JS 
here is an [example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd use an `iframe`. The `<iframe>` tag specifies an **inline frame**. An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Try this:

```
<body>
  <iframe src="testing.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</body>
```

You'll also need some CSS, as follows:

```css
body{
   border: 0;
}
iframe {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

So, building on the code above here's an example snippet:

```css
body {
  border: 0;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="https://example.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</body>
```

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

There some ways you may try, but you may need to read bout it:

1. `<template/>` , placeholder tags for you to write new [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)
2. Try using Javascript (limited that you must abide to CORs and also no inline scripts). E.g.

   `fetch('https://url.com/something.html').then(data => document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = data.text())`
3. Use IFrames. `<iframe src=""/>`
4. Use some templating engine depending on languages, like

- PUG/Jade (template generator),
- Freemarker (Java),
- React, angular (JS).

The second 2) option will always introduce security issues and you will also hit some roadblocks in future, e.g. executing scripts, etc.

The third 3) might be a better option if you are putting whole html. Your worries will be in interaction between current page and resize.

But directly injecting HTML on runtime introduces risks, you won't know what will the contents are and it's not a recommended way. You'll also risk into mismatch Html child, e.g.
`<html><title><html><title></title></html><body>..`